MSB3274 import error for a framework version i don't even want to use
I'm trying to do multitargeting for .Net Framework v4.5.2 and .net standard2.0 my project file has the following targeting options attributes:
    <TargetFramework>v4.5.2</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFrameworks>v4.5.2;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>

I don't see where in my project there is anything referencing framework 4.0 but still I get:
[...]\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): 
    warning MSB3274: The primary reference "RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0,
        Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was
        built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher
        version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Followed by a lot of CS0234 (type or namespace within RestSharp not found)
The obj folder contains a file called ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes" so for some reason VS thinks I want to target 4.0. The obj folder also contains two folders netstandard2.0 and v4.5.2 which confuses me since here MSBuild seems to get what I want.
I've tried to clean the solution and also manually deleted obj and bin folders. Without any success.
Do you know where this could arise from or how to further debug? Thanks!
EDIT:
Just saw when opening the Solution in VS2019 I get:
Invalid restore input. Duplicate frameworks found: 'net40, net40'. Input files: [myproject.csproj]
But greping for net40 withing myproject.csproj has no matches.

Could it be the target of the RestSharp Lib that's the problem, not your target?

RestSharp 105.2.3 doesn't support netstandard2.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/105.2.3#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Also "v4.5.2" doesn't seem to be a valid TFM? Although maybe it's supported for back compat reasons. The correct TFM is "net452". Also just specify TargetFrameworks, not TargetFramework

@Fildor The error clearly sais it's the how I said. But you still think it's the other way around? How would I check that?

@canton7 RestSharp not supportig netstandard: Well that's true but I think unrelated will figure that out later.

@Jakob There's a lot of backwards compat weirdness, with libraries which only target .NET Framework (and not .NET Standard) being considered valid even when the parent project targets .NET Standard, etc, from the time when .NET Standard was just being introduced. I don't fully understand what would cause your exact error, but wouldn't be surprised if an earlier incompatibility (such as RestSharp not supporting .NET Standard) caused MSBuild to go down that path, which then encountered a further error.

In other words, I wouldn't ignore the fact that RestSharp doesn't target .NET Standard and you do. Although you might think it's unconnected, it might very well be the source of your error!

So, given we figured out that you cannot target both 4.5.2 and netstandard2.0 with RestSharp at the same time - you'll probably need to make a (hard) decision: Will you give up supporting legacy, long out-of-support frameworks?

@canton7 okay then i'll try to fix that first, did you see my edit though?

@Jakob Yep. I suspect that might be due to your duplicate TargetFramework and TargetFrameworks, and possibly also using v4.5.2 instead of net452 (I wonder whether it's mis-interpreting v4.5.2 as .NET Framework 4.0 somehow?). Fix the problems we've identified (in case they're causing additional confusing weirdness), clean, rebuild, see what happens then

@Fildor Not a decision I can make. It's one i'm arguing for but on my level it's either crosstarget or staying with legacy out of support versions only.

.NET 4.5.2 is out of support, and that version of RestSharp has a high-severity vulnerability in it. Pick a supported .NET Framework version (.NET Framework 4.6.2 or above), and use a recent version of RestSharp (the latest version supports .NET 4.6.1+ and .NET Standard 2.0)

Well, there's a point where the decision takes you. This should give you some leverage to advocate for upgrades. :)

@canton7 everything stays exactly the same when putting net452 there

@Jakob Share your latest csproj?

@Fildor I think this is a little bit offtopic but theres not much leverage. The software is only used for internal processes on an internal network. The only leverage i have is that it's terribly anoying not beeing able to use software that has been written past 2015.

@canton7 re: newest .csproj: i now only have the line <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks> in there.

It's political, I see. That's a minefield. In that case you can only roll with it and wait for the ricochet.

And you've done a full clean, followed by dotnet restore (or a full rebuild)?

@canton7 yes. I've saved the .csproj i'ive done build -> clean solution, i've closed vs2019 and reopend the solution and nothing chaged. I'm not the only one facing the proplem though. But there's no clear solution in that issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10289

Hi @Jakob, did you try to use  to ignore the warning?

The error usually occurs when the build version is a higher version number than the version that was pre-installed with the version of Visual Studio.
Please try to edit the project file to ignore target framework version mismatches as follows and see if it unblocks you.
<PropertyGroup>
  <ResolveAssemblyReferenceIgnoreTargetFrameworkAttributeVersionMismatch>true</ResolveAssemblyReferenceIgnoreTargetFrameworkAttributeVersionMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>

